# Count query not grouping properly

Tags: mysql, count

I'm having some issues figuring out what seems to be simple, but it's eluding me. Any help is much appreciated.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `match_history` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `match_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `team_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `player_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `map` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `score` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `outcome` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `notes` longtext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=271 ;

match_id links to matches.id
team_id links to matchteams.id
player_id links to persons.id
```

What I want to see is wins and losses per team, but I'm having issues since the match_history table above will have multiple rows per match and per team.

For instance:

```
INSERT INTO `match_history` (`id`, `match_id`, `team_id`, `player_id`, `map`, `score`, `outcome`, `notes`) VALUES
(221, 44, 2, 124, 'Village', 1570, 'Win', ''),
(220, 44, 2, 115, 'Village', 1600, 'Win', ''),
(219, 44, 2, 92, 'Village', 2740, 'Win', ''),
(218, 44, 4, 105, 'Village',1000, 'Loss', ''),
(217, 44, 4, 111, 'Village', 1220, 'Loss', ''),
(216, 44, 4, 130, 'Village', 1440, 'Loss', ''),
(215, 44, 4, 122, 'Village', 2160, 'Loss', ''),
(214, 44, 4, 130, 'Seatown', 1410, 'Loss', ''),
(213, 44, 4, 122, 'Seatown', 1600, 'Loss', ''),
(212, 44, 4, 111, 'Seatown', 1790, 'Loss', ''),
(211, 44, 4, 105, 'Seatown', 1790, 'Loss', ''),
(210, 44, 2, 113, 'Seatown', 1020, 'Win', ''),
(209, 44, 2, 124, 'Seatown', 1480, 'Win', ''),
(207, 44, 2, 115, 'Seatown', 2850, 'Win', ''),
(208, 44, 2, 92, 'Seatown', 2160, 'Win', ''),
(222, 44, 2, 113, 'Village', 900, 'Win', ''),
(223, 45, 1, 123, 'Hardhat', 2970, 'Win', ''),
(224, 45, 1, 26, 'Hardhat', 2930, 'Win', ''),
(225, 45, 1, 107, 'Hardhat', 1710, 'Win', ''),
(226, 45, 3, 101, 'Hardhat', 1530, 'Loss', ''),
(227, 45, 3, 100, 'Hardhat', 1420, 'Loss', ''),
(228, 45, 3, 125, 'Hardhat', 1010, 'Loss', ''),
(229, 45, 1, 107, 'Seatown', 2520, 'Win', ''),
(230, 45, 1, 123, 'Seatown', 2260, 'Win', ''),
(231, 45, 1, 26, 'Seatown', 1560, 'Win', ''),
(232, 45, 3, 101, 'Seatown', 1510, 25, 3, 42, 0.6, 0, 0, 0, 'Loss', ''),
```

This is the query I was using, but it's counting each row as 1.

```
select mh.team_id as team_id, COUNT(distinct(mh.match_id)) as matches, 
  count(mh.map) as maps, mh.outcome, SUM(IF(mh.outcome='Win',1,0)) as wins,   
  SUM(IF(mh.outcome='Loss',1,0)) as losses, m.id, mt.name as teamname
FROM match_history mh, matches m, ladders l, match_teams mt
WHERE mh.team_id = mt.id and mh.match_id = m.id and 
  m.ladder_id = l.id and l.type = 'internal'
GROUP by mh.team_id
ORDER by wins desc
```

Comment: whats up with the last insert?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL, unlike standard SQL, allows you to include columns in the field-list (the `SELECT` clause) that aren't in the `GROUP BY` and aren't aggregate columns — see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html — but you have to be careful, or you can get unpredictable results. In your case, you're `GROUP`ing `BY` `mh.team_id`, so you can safely include columns that depend on the team-ID (for example, `mt.name` should be safe), but you *cannot* select `mh.outcome` and `m.id`, since these depend on the specific match. So, I'll remove those columns.

Then, we need to change the `SUM(1-or-0)` to `COUNT(DISTINCT match-ID-or-NULL)` so that we only count distinct match-IDs:

```
select mh.team_id as team_id,
       COUNT(distinct(mh.match_id)) as matches,
       count(mh.map) as maps,
       COUNT(DISTINCT IF(mh.outcome='Win',m.id,NULL)) as wins,
       COUNT(DISTINCT IF(mh.outcome='Loss',m.id,NULL)) as losses,
       mt.name as teamname
  FROM match_history mh,
       matches m,
       ladders l,
       match_teams mt
 WHERE mh.team_id = mt.id
   and mh.match_id = m.id
   and m.ladder_id = l.id
   and l.type = 'internal'
 GROUP by mh.team_id
 ORDER by wins desc
```

which should do what you want.

Comment: Good answer, although I would argue that even selecting columns that depend on the group-by columns should be avoided.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, however it appears that I'm still not getting the data I expect.

Comment: Whoops. I hit enter... I am getting counts back for each person entry. For instance, if there are 4 people on a team, I am getting back 4 instead of 1 because it appears to count each entered row instead of the unique combination of match_id and team_id.

Comment: @PaulIlle: Oh, I see. I didn't notice that you had a separate record for each player. That's really broken -- you need to normalize your database -- but I've edited my answer with a query to work around that.

Comment: ruakh, what are your suggestions for normalizing this data?

Comment: @PaulIlle: I don't know, sorry -- the more I look at your data, the less I understand it -- but many of the fields on `match_history` are functionally dependent on `(match_id, team_id)`. Maybe you need to have a separate `match_team_history` and `match_player_history`?

Comment: @ruakh I took your words for it & tried to build that design but in the end it ended up doing almost same thing but with more redundancy. I may be wrong but I dont think you can simply this table more than this without sacrificing efficiency & physical space. *sigh* its such a sad thing.. & troublesome at the same time

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure since havent tried sql in a while but try this..
let me know if it gives any error

```
select team_id, count(*)  from match_history
where outcome = 'Win'
group by team_id
```

if it works then we can union it with losses

EDIT:
Such a troublesome thing...
You better make a good use of this.. i have spent days (well, atleast minutes :P ) getting to this
i have tested it in SQL Server to tailor it to mysql if needed.
Good Luck! :D

```
select aa.tid, aa.win, COALESCE(c.loss, 0) from 
(SELECT distinct a.team_id tid, COALESCE(b.win, 0) win
  FROM [match_history] a
  left join
  (select team_id, count(*) win
  from [match_history]
  where outcome = 'Win'
  group by team_id) b
  on a.team_id = b.team_id)aa

  left join
  (select team_id, count(*) loss
  from [match_history]
  where outcome = 'Loss'
  group by team_id) c
  on aa.tid = c.team_id
```

Result:

```
tid win Loss
1   6   0
2   7   0
3   0   3
4   0   8
```

Comment: Bhrugesh, thanks for it still shows too many. ruakh, what are your suggestions for normalizing this data?

Comment: @PaulIlle I hope this new query works for you.. Good luck! :D